# Shell variable is being treated as command

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have written this small script to compare file name with the files in one folder and copy them to another folder if they do not exist in the first one. Please refer code. But for some reason Ubuntu 15.04 is treating my variable as command and giving me following error:

./COPY_FILES.sh: line 8: FILE_EXIST_IN_SUPER_STRING: command not found

```
while read NAME1
do
    FILE_EXIST_IN_SUPER_STRING = 0  
    while read NAME2
    do
        if [ "$NAME1" == "$NAME2" ]
         then
            FILE_EXIST_IN_SUPER_STRING = 1
        fi
    done < file_superstring.txt

    if [ "$FILE_EXIST_IN_SUPER_STRING" == 0 ]
        then
        cp Master/"$NAME1" Non-SuperString/"$NAME1"
    fi
done < Total_files.txt
```

Comment: Remove the `spaces` between the `variable` and `value`

Comment: Please take a shell scripting class before asking here. It seems that you are missing the basics.

Comment: Thanks guys. I know it is a silly question to ask and I searched it on google earlier but did not find answer. I had just created this small script to support me for some project. Thanks a lot for your quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third line should have **no spaces**.

It should be:

```
FILE_EXIST_IN_SUPER_STRING=0
```